# Set an image as a background for a DrawingArea

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I'm doing a platformer game using gtkmm and cairo, and i can't find a way to set an image as a background, so i don't have to redraw it on every draw event. I'm managing images as pixbufs.
Is it actually possible, or am i thinking it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redraw events are always necessary. The difference is about who has to take care of them. Lower level libraries such as Cairo require you to do that.

Maybe you should look into [Goocanvas](https://developer.gnome.org/goocanvas/stable/). Particularly for games where you have to move things around easily and capture events, a higher level library than Cairo is handy. GooCanvas also handles screen redraws.

You can just put in the image with GooCanvasImage, and forget about it.

If you're not bound to C++, then have a look at [PyGame](http://www.pygame.org/hifi.html) for Python - it not only handles those events, but provides loads of other tools for game programming.